# Result is undefined when performing two async calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am performing two calls and always getting a result of undefined as the action is aysnchronous. Is there anyway to wait until a result is valid before moving on?

```
function delay(ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function isAdmin() {
  delay(500);
  return await this.authService.userProfile$.toPromise();
}

console.log(isAdmin())

var result = isAdmin().then(response => {
  if (response != null) {
    console.log(response);
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  return this.webService.getUser(response);
});
```

Comment: It should be `await delay(500);`, or the delay call is pretty useless.

Comment: Please learn to use observables `this.authService.userProfiles$.pipe(delay(500))` everything you're doing here is an anti pattern in Angular.